# How to get an integer value from a 'for' loop in Python and print it

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, tkinter, canopy

I am currently using Canopy to run my code. I was trying to fetch some integer data from the entry box in my GUI according to the number that I give in the `for` loop and print it. It is not working.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win- x86_64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\SIMULATOR\Desktop\python\life cycle graph\try4.py", line 24, in const
z=int(s)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('1000x600+400+400')

def const():

    const_entries = []

    for i in range(0, 4):

        en = Entry(root)
        en.pack()
        en.place(x=50, y = 200 + 25*i)

        s = en.get()
        z = int(s)

        const_entries.append(z)

        j = i + 1

        label = Label(root, text="Alternative %r"%j)
        label.pack()
        label.place(x = 200, y = 200 + 25*i)

        print const_entries

    button1 = Button(root, text="Construction cost", command = const).grid(row = 15, column = 0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is obvious that i need to convert the Entry into integer to save it into the list but the program shows error as soon as i declare the Entry as Integer,

Comment: ``z=int(s)`` fails because ``s`` is an empty string. Did you miss something at ``s=en.get()``?

Comment: Is there an error like `TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid`

Answer (score 3):

Clarification: Assuming that `s` isn't empty (`en.get()` returns some number).

**Check out this example:**

`int('55.500000')`

It gets you a: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '55.500000'`

And:

> `float('55.500000')`

Gets you: `55.5`

So just cast to `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: No. This will raise a ``ValueError`` because the str ``s`` still is empty.

Comment: I clarified my answer on the first line=]

Answer (score 0):

When literal `s` couldn't be converted to `int`, `int(s)` failed.

```
try:
    z = int(s)
except ValueError:
    z = 0
```

Comment: So you want that your code works wrong? Because `0` is not the value which is expected during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `en.get()` at this point, it will return `''` and then `int('')` will raise an error. Maybe before getting the integer you want to set an integer as string to the `entry`.

When you write `button1 = Button(root, text="Construction cost", command = const).grid(row = 15, column = 0)` `button1` will not be a `Button` instance; `button1` should be the result of the `grid` function.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the other answers, your code is failing, because your entries are empty when you call the `const` method.

Assuming that you want to enter something in your entry boxes and then print the alternatives I guess code like this would do the job:

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry('1000x600+400+400')

def const():
    const_entries = []
    for i in range(4):
        s = entryArray[i].get()
        z = int(s)
        const_entries.append(z)

    print const_entries

button1 = Button(root, text="Construction cost", command = const).grid(row = 15, column = 0)

entryArray = []

for i in range(0,4):
    entryArray.append(Entry(root))

    #Insert default value 0
    entryArray[i].insert(0, 0)
    entryArray[i].pack()
    entryArray[i].place(x = 50, y = 200 + 25*i)
    label = Label(root, text="Alternative %d"%(i+1))
    label.pack()
    label.place(x = 200, y = 200 + 25*i)

root.mainloop()
```

This way you create the entries at startup and you give the user the time to enter something. When you press the <kbd>Construction cost</kbd> button the `const` function is called which will read the content of your entries and print them out.

**Update**

If you then want the user to enter the number of entries I'd suggest using a class and defining two buttons:

- One for creating the entries after the user has entered the number
- One for processing the number the user enters in the created entries

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry('1000x600+400+400')

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        Label(root, text='Number of Entries').grid(row = 15, column = 0)
        self.numEntry = Entry(root)
        self.numEntry.grid(row = 15, column = 1)
        self.numEntry.insert(0, 0)
        Button(root, text="Build entries", command = self.buildEntries).grid(row = 15, column = 3)
        Button(root, text = "Construction cost", command = self.const).grid(row = 18, column = 0)

    def buildEntries(self):
        self.entryArray = []
        numEntries = int(self.numEntry.get())

        for i in range(numEntries):
            self.entryArray.append(Entry(root))
            #Insert default value 0
            self.entryArray[i].insert(0, 0)
            self.entryArray[i].pack()
            self.entryArray[i].place(x = 50, y = 200 + 25*i)
            label=Label(root, text="Alternative %d"%(i+1))
            label.pack()
            label.place(x = 200, y = 200 + 25*i)

    def const(self):
        const_entries = []
        numVal = len(self.entryArray)
        for i in range(numVal):
            s = self.entryArray[i].get()
            z = int(s)
            const_entries.append(z)

        print 'Const Entries:', const_entries

m = MainWindow()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..it really helped..i just want to add one more question here...What if i want the user to input the number of Entry boxes first and then take the user input in those entries into a list for further calculation...

Comment: You mean to create the entries based on an user input and then having the user fill these entries with values?

Comment: I would really appreciate it, if you could help me make it..!

Comment: the No. of Entries should be input by user in an Entry box..!